# Is there anyway to reduce funds confirmation timing in coinpayments api?

Tags: blockchain, payment-gateway, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, coinpayments-api

I recently used [CoinPayments](https://coinpayments.net) API on my website but the expiration time of the invoice is 8hrs. Is there any possible way to reduce it to minutes?

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation when [creating a transaction](https://www.coinpayments.net/apidoc-create-transaction) - the answer is no. 
The timeout appears to not be a parameter you can set, only something you get back in the response.

I would suggest contacting them via their [support options](https://www.coinpayments.net/supwiz-merchant) and see if it's something that's set at an account level.